# New SQL installation getting installation services error

Tags: sql-server

We've set up a new SQL v18.5 server running on Windows 2016.  We're seeing these errors in the log every two minutes:

> Login failed for user 'Domain\ServerName$'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]

It's for user NT Service\NT SERVICE\SSISScaleOutMaster140

I did a little digging, and the answer seemed to be to add a login in SQL for NT SERVICE\SSISScaleOutMaster140, which I did.  After that I started getting this error:

> Login failed for user 'Domain\SERVERNAME$'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'SSISDB'. [CLIENT: ]

This SQL server is for a couple of specific applications we have, we do no development.  Could it be that SSIS was installed and simply shouldn't have been?

Comment: What is SQL Server v18.5? That sounds like Management Studio, a client tool, not SQL Server. Did you mean to install SSIS? Did you mean to install SSIS scale-out? Sounds like someone just installed and checked all the boxes...

Comment: Another party set up the SQL server initially; that's what I was thinking as well.  I assume SSIS is something that if you don't know what it is, you don't need it?